# WKWebView crash iOS9

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I get an unknown error with WKWebView on my simulator. A friend gets the same with his Iphone.
When I load a page from a web server, I try to click a button inside the page, but the webView crashes and I see a blank page on the screen. It is not a JavaScript issue.

I found similar issues but no solutions. (some people mentioned CGRectMake or 32/64 bits compatibility...)

My code is here:

```
 - (void) webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error url:(NSString *)url {

    WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc]
                                             init];

   WKUserContentController* userController = [[WKUserContentController alloc]init];

    [userController addScriptMessageHandler: self name:@"musique"];
    [userController addScriptMessageHandler: self name:@"upload"];
    configuration.userContentController = userController;

    self.webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-20) configuration:configuration];

    [self.view addSubview:self.webView];
     NSLog(@"ici web");
    // Setup WKUserContentController instance for injecting user script




    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];



}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you may cause a deadlock in JS, or some recursive calls fill up the stack – because my friend and I have no experienced such thing on our phones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by executing funtion `addScriptMessageHandler` twice again, You shuld place your follow code in the function `viewDidLoad`:

```
WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc]
                                         init];
WKUserContentController* userController = [[WKUserContentController alloc]init];

[userController addScriptMessageHandler: self name:@"musique"];
[userController addScriptMessageHandler: self name:@"upload"];
configuration.userContentController = userController;

self.webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-20) configuration:configuration];

[self.view addSubview:self.webView];
 NSLog(@"ici web");
// Setup WKUserContentController instance for injecting user script

[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
```

Comment: I mean that the function `- (void) webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error url:(NSString *)url` may be executed twice when WKWebView load the website.